# Styling sibiling li items of list on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have a list of items and when I hover over the last one, I want all others to change their background-color as well. So far, I tried few workarounds but without success.

```
<ul class ='profile'>
<li> item 1 </li>
<li> item 2 </li>
<li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

```
ul.profile > li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `>` ?? why not apply it directly.

Comment: This cant really be done efficently with only css, are you using pure js, or jquery?

Comment: There is no selector that can target previous siblings. For that you need a script, or use Flexbox, where one can have one order visually, and another in markup.

Comment: The dupe link has some tricks as well, the Flexbox solution included.

Comment: must it all be one (1) list?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
ul.profile:hover > li:not(:hover) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
ul.profile > li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/nr48qocd/ I don't need the others colored in yellow, but if I change it to red, doesn't matter which one I hover, the other will get colored. Only last item of list should trigger coloring of others on hover

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change the background of the whole ul when hovering over a certain li then you can use a little css trick with pointer-events.

You need to set the <ul> with `pointer-events: none;` , and the <li> that you want to hover over with `pointer-events: auto;`.

**Note:** Because you disable pointer-events, links etc. won't work either.

A code snippet as example:

```css
ul.profile {  
    pointer-events: none;
}

ul.profile li:nth-child(3) {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

ul.profile:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class ='profile'>
<li> item 1 </li>
<li> item 2 </li>
<li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this one looks like the solution, but i cannot click the other links now